# Adding multiple hlines to a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Adding multiple hlines to plot. The xstart and xfinsh values are in a  pandas dataframe

```
xstart  xfinish
0.00    6.30
37.45   43.95
57.16   64.73
64.73   71.97
76.49   82.79
84.65   92.77
125.48  131.69
131.69  139.98
```

I want to add a hline onto the plot for each of the rows. The yvalue of the hline is y=1.

I have tried this:

```
plt.hlines(1,xstart ,xfinish)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass arrays of `y` and `xmin`, `xmax` of equal length. Use:

```
plt.hlines([1] * len(df), df['xstart'], df['xfinish'])
```

[image]